# Kubernetes operator without CRD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I'm looking to create a custom Kubernetes controller; I do mean **controller** in this case because I'm not looking to create a CRD, and thus, not an operator. Basically, it would be similar to the [External DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns) project in that it watches annotations, and takes actions based on the presence / absence of that annotation.

Is there a a simple example of something like this? Most of the resources I find are for operators and creating CRDs, but my use case just involves looking at an annotation only.

Comment: [Kubebuilder](https://book.kubebuilder.io) and [controller-runtime](https://godoc.org/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime) are official Kubernetes projects to support this.  You can probably use Kubebuilder to make a skeleton and then rip out the CRD parts of it.

Comment: If you found a solution to this that you like, could you give yourself an answer?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone interested, here's a simple operator without CRD: https://github.com/busser/label-operator

This operator uses only the Pod kind:

```
// SetupWithManager sets up the controller with the Manager.
func (r *PodReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&corev1.Pod{}). // <<< here
        Complete(r)
}
```

Checks if there is a label on the pod and changes it if necessary:

```
labelShouldBePresent := pod.Annotations[addPodNameLabelAnnotation] == "true"
labelIsPresent := pod.Labels[podNameLabel] == pod.Name

if labelShouldBePresent == labelIsPresent {
    // The desired state and actual state of the Pod are the same.
    // No further action is required by the operator at this moment.
    log.Info("no update required")
    return ctrl.Result{}, nil
}

if labelShouldBePresent {
    // If the label should be set but is not, set it.
    if pod.Labels == nil {
        pod.Labels = make(map[string]string)
    }
    pod.Labels[podNameLabel] = pod.Name
    log.Info("adding label")
} else {
    // If the label should not be set but is, remove it.
    delete(pod.Labels, podNameLabel)
    log.Info("removing label")
}
```

I hope I have helped in some way.